# Datatype conversion in sqlite

Tags: database

what query i used to change the column datatype from numberic to string in sqlite

because my android project not retrieve mobile number as

smsno1=m.getLong(0);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cast expression:
    `CAST(whatever) AS TYPE`